# Gradle WAR project setup

Tags: gradle, war

I have the following project structure. Gradle 3.1

```
RootProject
-- Project A <-- RESTful JAX-RS Project
-- Project B <-- Services Project containing EJB's
```

I want to assemble this project into one single WAR archive such as RootProject.war which would include Project A & B for deployment in an EAR archive (totally separate from this project).

How do I setup the root level build.gradle and the sub projects build.gradle files?

If I set the apply plugin: 'war' to the root build.gradle i get options for creating war archives from each project!